# Using multiple processing algorithms cause an 'attribute error'

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing

I have two processing algorithms in my plugin code and I want to use the **outputs** of them into a new algorithm, like this:

```
buff = processing.runandload('qgis:fixeddistancebuffer', layers[self.pic], 10 + (10 * (int(self.dlg.lcdNumber_1.value())) / 100), 5, True, None) 
# buff and buff2 are fine, they will add to canvas, no errors
buff2 = processing.runandload('qgis:fixeddistancebuffer', layers[self.pic], 30 + (30 * (int(self.dlg.lcdNumber_2.value())) / 100), 5, True, None)
```

and I want to use the two to a new algorithm like:

```
processing.runandload('qgis:difference', buff2['OUTPUT'], buff['OUTPUT'], None)
```

but it will give `AttributeError: FixedDistanceBuffer instance has no attribute '__getitem__'`
what can i do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two issues in your code.

1) It cannot be used buff2['OUTPUT'] or buff['OUTPUT'] as parameters with 'runandload' processing method. These parameters should be used with 'runalg' method.

2) In 'qgis:difference' is necessary one additional parameter: IGNORE_INVALID [ParameterBoolean].

Similar to your example, I tried out following code:

```
import processing

point1 = processing.getObjectFromName('point1')
point2 = processing.getObjectFromName('point2')

buff = processing.runalg('qgis:fixeddistancebuffer', 
                         point1, 
                         1000, 
                         5, 
                         True, 
                         None) 

buff2 = processing.runalg('qgis:fixeddistancebuffer', 
                          point2, 
                          2000, 
                          5, 
                          True, 
                          None)

processing.runandload('qgis:difference', 
                      buff2['OUTPUT'], 
                      buff['OUTPUT'], 
                      False, 
                      None)
```

After running it at Python Console of QGIS; with these point layers:

[image]

it was produced its respective buffers (not loaded at Map Canvas) and its difference; as it can be observed at following image:

[image]

However, if you also need to load buffers following code works adequately:

```
import processing

point1 = processing.getObjectFromName('point1')
point2 = processing.getObjectFromName('point2')

buff = processing.runalg('qgis:fixeddistancebuffer', 
                          point1, 
                          1000, 
                          5, 
                          True, 
                          None) 

copy_buff = QgsVectorLayer(buff['OUTPUT'],
                           'buff',
                           'ogr')

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(copy_buff)

buff2 = processing.runalg('qgis:fixeddistancebuffer', 
                           point2, 
                           2000, 
                           5, 
                           True, 
                           None)

copy_buff2 = QgsVectorLayer(buff2['OUTPUT'],
                            'buff2',
                            'ogr')

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(copy_buff2)


processing.runandload('qgis:difference', 
                      buff2['OUTPUT'], 
                      buff['OUTPUT'], 
                      False, 
                      None)
```

as it can be observed at following image:

[image]

**Editing Note:**

Following code works well too by using 'runandload' processing method for buffers.

```
import processing

point1 = processing.getObjectFromName('point1')
point2 = processing.getObjectFromName('point2')

buff = processing.runandload('qgis:fixeddistancebuffer', 
                              point1, 
                              1000, 
                              10, 
                              True, 
                              None) 

buff = processing.getObjectFromName('Buffer')

buff2 = processing.runandload('qgis:fixeddistancebuffer', 
                              point2, 
                              2000, 
                              10, 
                              True, 
                              None)

buff2 = processing.getObjectFromName('Buffer')

processing.runandload('qgis:difference', 
                      buff2, 
                      buff, 
                      False, 
                      None)
```